# getString from SharedPreferences always return default value for one value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i'm using this code in an activity

```
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    System.out.println(connections);
    String dir = prefs.getString("download_directory", "Download");
    System.out.println(dir);        
 }
```

My preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Downloads">
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="download_directory"
            android:title="@string/download_destination"
            android:summary="@string/download_description"
            android:defaultValue="FacebookPhotos"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/download_destination" />
        <CheckBoxPreference android:key="subdir_album"
            android:title="@string/download_album"
            android:summary="@string/download_album_description" />
     </PreferenceCategory>
  <PreferenceCategory android:title="Gallery">
     <EditTextPreference 
      android:key="connections"
      android:title="Concurrent connections"
      android:numeric="integer"
      android:maxLength="2" 
      android:defaultValue="7"
      android:dialogTitle="Concurrent connections" />
  </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

edited by

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
}
```

The problem is, when i get "connections" value it gives me the correct int, instead the getString for key "download_directory" always gives me the default value "Download"

Comment: Could you post the code for when you're setting the values?

Comment: There might be an error in the rest of your preferences.xml. Could you post the rest of it?

Answer (score 0):

> getString for key "download_directory" always gives me the default
>   value "Download"

This can only happen if "download_directory" is not set at all!

Comment: Seems that if i put a custom value it works. I thought that defaultValue in XML code would be passed by the getString/Int method if i dont change them, and second parameter in the method would be used only if method couldn't retrieve the value, instead the method return his second parameter if i dont change that value from settings, i hope i explained myself